# Changing "Bearer" to something else in the header (like "Token") for JWT

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am implementing the [Conduit](https://realworld-docs.netlify.app/docs/specs/backend-specs/introduction/) spec. For JWT, it requires the header for JWT tokens to be:

```
Authorization: Token jwt.token.here
```

With `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer`, the default header is "Authorization: Bearer {token goes here}". I've added an OnMessageReceived event that replaces the default "Bearer" with "Token".

However, for Swashbuckle, when adding a security scheme to Swashbuckle, I can't figure out a way to change the headers it generates to use "Token" instead of "Bearer". So, while I can fall back to Postman to make API requests, I'd really like to use Swashbuckle/OpenAPI/SwaggerUI instead.

Is there a setting or some way to override its use of "Bearer"? Or is this hardcoded and a new feature would need to be added to support that? Below is what I've tried, and it's not working. It falls back to "Bearer". If I set `Scheme` to "Token", it causes a runtime error.

```
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Your API", Version = "v1" });

                // Configure JWT authentication
                var securityScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                    Scheme = "Bearer",
                    BearerFormat = "JWT"
                };

                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Token", securityScheme);
                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id = "Token"
                            }
                        },
                        Array.Empty<string>()
                    }
                });
            });
```

Update:

Here's a screenshot of the prompt I get when I click the "Authorize" button in the Swagger UI:

[image: Swagger UI authorize prompt]

Note that it says "Token", probably from `AddSecurityDefinition` or `AddSecurityRequirement`, but it actually generates "Bearer". After I enter a value and click:

[image: Authorize prompt after entering a value]

Comment: In Swashbuckle, you typically enter "Bearer {token}" in the popup, so you need to manually prefix it with Bearer. Have you tried prefixing it with "Token {token}" instead to see if that works?

Comment: That is not what I'm seeing in the popup. I'll put a screenshot in the question, but it's just prompting me for the token value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenAPI specification does allow you to define alternative schemes for the Authorization header, though technically they should be well-known schemes registered here: https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml. "Token" is not in the list.

That said, you can probably extend Swashbuckle to output it. I believe the method would be to use `DocumentFilter<T>()` on the `SwaggerGenOptions` when registering Swashbuckle on your DI container. You can then add a filter that mutates the generated Swagger spec immediately after it is generated but before it is consumed. You should be able to adjust the security schemes, something like this:

```cs
private class DocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        swaggerDoc.Components.SecuritySchemes["SchemeName"].Scheme = "Token";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Only `Basic` or `Bearer` would be considerered as valid scheme with the configuration `Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,`

[image]

Even if  the value of the scheme is "Token" in the json file :
[image]

It would be blocked
[image]

However,when I try with the configuration   `Type = SecuritySchemeType.Apikey`,I could send token prefxing "Token" manually(seems a bug)

[image]
[image]

I tried with Swashbuckle.AspNetCore ver 6.2.3

Comment: Thank you, I'm inclined to accept this answer. I've also started a discussion on realworld. Maybe you can chime in there, too?